# if we have $f(n)=f(n-7)$ and $f(2)=3$ can we conclude that $f(n) \in \theta(1)$?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

if we have $f(n)=f(n-7)$ and $f(2)=3$ can we conclude that $f(n) \in \theta(1)$?
what if we also have $f(1)=2$?

Comment: There is no reason that the answer differs when you just know $f(2)$, or both $f(1),f(2)$, as the recurrence involves values $7$ units apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(n)=f(n-7)$, $f$ can take at most $7$ different values: $f(0),f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5)$ and $f(6)$ (the others values are obtained by translation)

So, obviously, $\forall n$, $|f(n)| \leq \max_{i=0}^6 |f(i)| = C$ and you indeed have $f \in \theta(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(n)=f(n-7)$$ implies $$f(n)=f(n\bmod7)$$ and the function is periodic, hence perforce $\Theta(1)$, regardless the particular values of $f(n\bmod7)$.

Comment: So in another word, every periodic function is a member of $\theta(1)$